# Packet "0x71" transmitted by iPad over control channel in HIDP Bluetooth connection

Tags: bluetooth, hid, l2cap

iPad is transmitting a `0x71` packet immediately after connecting over the control L2CAP channel in a Bluetooth HIDP connection.

Unless I respond with `0x00` byte immediately, over the same channel, iPad disconnects.

What does `0x71` mean? I cannot find this byte in HID specification nor in Bluetooth HIDP specification, although I might just be searching poorly. I have some indication it might be the `set_protocol` packet, probably setting to `REQUEST` protocol as opposed the `BOOT` protocol, but I can't confirm that.

I don't think it matters much that I'm connecting OS X machine with the iPad, with OS X machine serving as the server, but I'm noting it here in case it does.

Answer (score 2):

0x71 means "SET_PROTOCOL for Input reports". One can choose between Boot mode (0x70) and regular mode (0x71). See 7.4.6 of the HID_SPEC_V10 from Bluetooth.org for more details.